# single html form email sending with csv posting simltaniously

Tags: php, html, email, csv

I am having  HTML form with php code on submit, that sends E-mail. What I need is along with sending email, that details to be up-dated in csv file (with single submit button simultaneously.  The PHP code for sending E-mail is:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
        header('Location: error.html');
        exit;
           }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $place = $_POST['place'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_body = 
              "NAME:     $name\n".
              "PLACE:    $place\n".
              "EMAIL-ID: $email\n\n".
              "Message:  $message\n" ;
    $to = "to@xyz.com";
    //Send the email!
    mail($to, $email_body);
    //done
    header('Location: thank.html');
 ?>
```

When I add following code, it is not working:

```
$fp = fopen("datacsv.csv", "a+");

fputcsv($name, $place,  $email,  $message);
fclose($fp);
```

can any body guide me in correcting the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter for the function fputcsv() is the file handle and the second one is an array, so try this:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header('Location: error.html');
    exit;
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_body = "NAME:     $name\n".
              "PLACE:    $place\n".
              "EMAIL-ID: $email\n\n".
              "Message:  $message\n";

$to = "to@xyz.com";

//Send the email!
mail($to, "My Subject", $email_body);

$fp = fopen("datacsv.csv", "a+");
fputcsv($fp, array($name, $place,  $email,  $message));
fclose($fp);

//done
header('Location: thank.html');
?>
```

Be sure to add the code BEFORE the header() function. Also, check if the permissions are correct on the file datacsv.csv.

Comment: Where shall the csv file name to be added      "$fp = fopen("datacsv.csv", "a+");"

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question... either way, I changed my code to be exactly how you have to add to your .php file.

As for the .csv file, if it does not exist PHP will create it (a+ mode) in the same directory as the .php file.

Comment: According to PHP documentation, the mail() function has three mandatory parameters (http://php.net/mail), so I also added the missing one (subject) to my code. Test it now, please. If it still does not work, try commenting out the mail() line to check if the file gets created.